# What is the blue double arrow that appears over links?

Tags: html

Can someone tell me what this blue arrow is, why it appears over links and how I can stop it or remove it?  It keeps appearing on a set of links of a website that I am working on.

[image]

Comment: think this is an IE8 feature (or IE7) - called accelerator or something. Btw Use all kinds of browsers /ffox, chrome, safari/ to test your pages.

Answer (score 10):

Those are [accelerators in IE 8](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/internet-explorer/features/faster.aspx):

> Simply highlight text from any webpage, and then click on the blue Accelerator icon that appears above your selection to obtain driving directions, translate and define words, email content to others, search with ease, and more. For example, with the "Map with Bing" Accelerator in Internet Explorer 8, you can get an in-place view of a map displayed directly on the page.

They should appear only if you select text on the page, though.

Answer (score 5):

IE8 accelerator icon.  [Removal instructions.](http://www.ibgerm.com/tag/blue-arrow/)

Comment: 10 people "answer" & get upvoted, but only 1 answer to the question.  Good job.

Answer (score 4):

The blue arrow is an IE8 "feature" called "[accelerators](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/internet-explorer/features/faster.aspx)". Basically it's IE's way of saying, you're looking at something, here's a bunch of other related things you can look at. You can only turn it off in your Internet Options. It's not something (I believe) you can turn off for visitors to your site.

Answer (score 1):

The arrow image you posted looks like IE8 Accelerator.

Answer (score 0):

As stated, it is IE8's accelerator icon.  It's IE's attempt to add functionality that would typically be done with plugins in other browsers.

As [Chris Simmons](https://stackoverflow.com/users/208990/chris-simmons) suggested you can [disable the arrow](http://www.ibgerm.com/tag/blue-arrow/).

Answer (score 0):

I came here looking for the same answer - and I just figureed this out! :0) Ok everybody, here's teh deal:

It -IS- what's called an accelerator. For those of you using Windows XP (SP3), here is how to turn them on or off:

1. Click - START-> Settings ->Control Panel -> Internet Options
2. On your strting tab (GENERAL), at about the middle, you'll see "SEARCH - Change seech defaults" - click on teh button next to it that says "SETTINGS"
3. A special separate window will open

called "View & Manage Your Internet Explorer Add-Ons"

4. The 3rd selection down is "Accelerators" - clcik on it.
5. Now all the places that that accelerator icon appears, are listed. Simply click on each one & as u do, you will see that the bottom window changes and gives you the ability to DISABLE or ENABLE each type. Make your selections, or disable them all, whatever... You can even "Remove" each one, if you like. Note: the only way to get rid of some of these, is indeed to "remove" (delete) them altogether.
6. Now just click "close" at the bottom and this window will close & save those settings.
7. Click "OK" on the the INternet Option window.

That's it! You're done... and those pesky icons are gone! :0)

Hope this helps... :0)

Answer (score -1):

Alrighty, seems to me as though it is a plugin in your browser. It would help to know what browser you are using and what extensions or plugins or add-ons you have installed.

Should be simple to remove, just disable or uninstall those.

Answer (score -1):

Can you provide a link to the website so that we can deduce what is causing it? My guess would be that it is either a plugin on the web page or a plugin on your computer.